# SEO Question, and about Server.Transfer (Asp.net)

Tags: seo, server.transfer

So, we're trying to up our application in the rankings in the search engines, and one way our SEO guy told us to do that was to register similar domains...for example we have something like

```
http://www.myapplication.com/parks.html
```

so..we acquired the domain `parks.com` (again just an example).

Now when people go to `http://www.parks.com` ...we want it to display the content of `http://www.myapplication.com/parks.html`.

I could just put a forwarding page there, but from what i've been told that makes us look bad because it's technically a permanent redirect..and we're trying to get higher in the search engine rankings, not lower.

Is this a situation where we would use the Server.Transfer method of ASP.net?

How are situations like this handled, because I've defiantly seen this done by many websites.

We also don't want to cheat the system, we are showing relevant content and not spam or tricking customers in anyway, so the proper way to do achieve what i'm looking for would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your "similar" domain names to host individual and targetted landing pages that will point to your master content.

It's easier to manage and you will get a higher conversion rate.

Having to create individual page will force you to write relevent content and will increase the popularity of the page.

I also suggest you to not only build landing pages, but mini sites (of few pages).

SEO is sa very high demanding task.

Regarding technical aspects: `Server.Transfer` is what you should use. Never use `Response.Redirect`, Google and other search engines will drop your ranking.

I used permanent URL rewrite in the past. I changed my website and since lots of traffic was coming from others website linking mine, I wanted to have a permanent solution.

Read more about URL rewriting : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx